# Open iframe source in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've got an iframe that people can navigate through to get to a specific place, but as it is cross-domain some of the javascript on the site doesn't work (Such as looking at product history for example...)

I've been trying to find a way to make a button that will take whatever page the user is on in the iframe and open that link in a new tab.

While trying to research if this was possible, all I could find is people opening links from within an iframe in a new tab, which is **not** what I need.

I need to make a button that onclick will open a new tab with whatever link the user is currently on in the iframe.

I haven't really tried many things because I cannot find anything on the subject (Probably due to terrible wording), but I'm thinking my best chance is jquery/javascript, however, I'm not very fluent in javascript.

So my question is, is it possible to open an iframes url into a new tab, and if so, what would be the most efficient way to do so?

*The website that is in my iframe is cross-domain and I cannot edit its source.*

What I currently have is this:

```
<iframe id="iframe" class="frame" name="iframe" height="100%" width="100%" onload="refreshLink(this.contentWindow.location.href)"></iframe>
```

Note: The src is set by javascript on page load.

Under that I have:

```
                                <script>
                                var hyperLink = document.getElementById("iframe").src;

                                function refreshLink(link) {
                                    hyperLink = link;
                                    document.getElementById("button").href=hyperLink;
                                }
                                </script>
```

Above all of that I have:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info" id="button">Open in R1</a>
```

But, when I click the button at any given time it opens a new tab to the same url I was at before (a tab that goes to the same page the iframe is displayed on).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this should be possible

For iframes displaying the same domain content you can get the current site url with something like this:

```
document.getElementById("myframeID").contentWindow.location.href
```

But for cross-domain iframes you will get the following error when trying to get the location on the site the same way:

```
VM2536:2 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

However this seems to work to get proper URL from cross-domain iframes

```
document.getElementById('myframeID').src
```

To finish off you could do something like this (assuming you use jQuery by your tags):

```
$('body').on('click','#button', function(){
   var url = document.getElementById('myframeID').src;
   var tabOrWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
   tabOrWindow.focus();
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a starter. With markup like this:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://yourwebsite.com"></iframe>
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="button">Click here</a>
```

Start with some JS that changes the anchor's `href` to the `src` of your `iframe`:

```
var hyperLink = document.getElementById("myIframe").src;
document.getElementById("button").href=hyperLink;
```

Add an `onload` attribute to your `iframe`:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="http://yourwebsite.com" onload="refreshLink(this.contentWindow.location.href)">
</iframe>
```

The line `onload="refreshLink(this.contentWindow.location.href)"` fetches the current URL of the iframe where the user's been navigating and sends it as an argument for the function `refreshLink`.

Then we can declare that function, and the full JS code would look like this:

```
var hyperLink = document.getElementById("myIframe").src;

function refreshLink(link) {
    hyperLink = link;
    document.getElementById("button").href=hyperLink;
}
```

This works, but it's subject to whatever policies each website has regarding iframes and http/https.

Comment: This seems to point me straight back to the URL the iframe is displayed?

Comment: Do you mean the original one? I tested my script on my server and it updates the link to wherever the user is in the iframe at that moment.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, can you look at my first post and review my code?